# Using ex-navigation with exponent.js how do you route to a new stack?

Tags: react-native, ex-navigation

I wish to trigger navigation to a details screen from a redux action - how do i do that with exponent ex-navigation?  Should I use `navigation.performAction` ?  Where's the documentation for that method?  This would be a route with a fresh stack since they would be coming from a create screen and they shouldn't press back to the create form.  This would also be a route that exists outside the tab navigation.